# Python: get the minimum length of space that captures all the non zero values of an array with looping allowed

Tags: python, numpy

Examples:

1)

```
 v                 v
[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]
 ^                 ^
```

would return a result of 10 as this is the `minimum length` of space between the first instance of a nonzero value and the last (bolded).
If we instead considered the following:

```
                 v v
[1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0] 
                 ^ ^
```

and looped to capture all the nonzero values, the length of space would be 13 so 10 is our answer.

2)

```
     v             v
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]
     ^             ^
```

would return a result of 5 since looping is allowed. If we instead considered the following:

```
     v               v
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1] 
     ^               ^
```

and did not loop, the length of space would be 9 so 5 is our answer.

Comment: I see no question here... Please refer to how to ask a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean with looping allowed or not allowed ? minimal space is just the difference of the indexes, right? why is `5` the answer in the 2nd example

Comment: Go from the left until you hit 1, and call this `a`. Go from the right until you hit 1, and call this `b`. Then check `b - a`. You can also check `length - b + a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.sign` + `np.argmax` to the find the index of the *first* non-zero value, and `np.cumsum` + `np.argmax` to find the index of the *last* non-zero value. Then subtract those:

```
>>> a = [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0]
>>> np.cumsum(a).argmax() - np.sign(a).argmax() + 1
9
```

- [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) essentially reduces each value in the array to it's sign, so negative numbers become `-1`, positive numbers become `1`, and `0` stays `0`.
- [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) returns the 0-based index of the first occurence of the largest value in the array, which will be `1` due to `np.sign`, so it will be the index of the first `1`, which works nicely for this case.
- [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) performs a cumulative sum accross all the items of the array. Because of this, the first occurence of the largest value in the array will be the last non-zero value, so `np.argmax` again is perfect.